# Caching queryset with list

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a query like this

```
Row.objects.filter(status=True)
```

And my colleague said that: If you cover it with

```
list(Row.objects.filter(status=True))
```

it will be cached. Is this true?

I read that: list() uses to do [force evaluation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/).

Answer (score 2):

The evaluation is probably the same thing that your colleague is talking about, as mentioned in the docs, it gets stored in the querysets cache so it is not needed to be reevaluated every time you need the results.

Relevant docs on [Caching and querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

> In a newly created QuerySet, the cache is empty. The first time a QuerySet is evaluated – and, hence, a database query happens – Django saves the query results in the QuerySet’s cache and returns the results that have been explicitly requested (e.g., the next element, if the QuerySet is being iterated over). Subsequent evaluations of the QuerySet reuse the cached results.

As you have mentioned, using `list` is one of the ways you can evaluate a queryset

Comment: That is correct, but it had to be set that it is evaluated the first time you use it, forcing premature evaluation using `list` doesn't generally make any sense (there may be however some fringe cases where it could be useful). So I'd say OP's colleague is NOT right: generally there is no reason to force queryset to evaluate using `list`.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer - True, I was trying to avoid any opinion on whether or not the colleague is right since I have enough office politics of my own :P In my opinion, it definitely is better to only evaluate a queryset when you need the results